# Cheerio.load messes with responses for Google Assistant

Tags: node.js, promise, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, cheerio

I have this intent that has a cheerio.load() being called and it messes with with the responses. The Google Assistant keeps telling me that no response has been set even though later down in the code I have responses. The console is also telling me that an async call wasn't being returned to the handler, which I believe is the cheerio.load(). Is there anyway I can fix this so that it continues looking for the correct conv.ask at the bottom of the code? It still continues to run down to there too, for the console.log(map) shows up. Thanks for any help!

```
app.intent("late drop", (conv,{term,year}) => {
var date = new Date();
var month;
if(term == null){
    month = date.getMonth();

    if(month >= 9 && month <=12){
        term = "fall";
        //console.log("fall")
    }
    else if (month >= 1 && month <= 5) {
        term = "spring";
        //console.log("spring")
    }
    else {
        term = "summer";
        //console.log("summer")
    }
}
if(year == null){
    yearDig = date.getFullYear();
    year = yearDig;
    //console.log(year)
}
var strYear = year.toString();
var semester = term+strYear.substr(2);
const options = {
    uri: `https://www.registrar.psu.edu/academic_calendar/${semester}.cfm`,
    transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
  }
};
rp(options)
.then(($) => {
    let map = {};
    let columnOne = [];
    let columnThree = [];

    $('table').find('tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function (index, element) {
        columnOne.push($(element).text());
      });

    $('table').find('tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function (index, element) {
        columnThree.push($(element).text());
    });

    columnOne.forEach((item, i) => {
        map[item] = columnThree[i];
    });

    console.log(map);
    date = map["2Late Drop Begins"];
    conv.ask("The late drop period begins on " + map["2Late Drop Begins"])
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    conv.ask("An error occured, please try again.");
})
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with cheerio.

It looks like you are using `request-promise` or `request-promise-native` to make your HTTP call. This does an asynchronous operation that will return a Promise (as is evidenced by your use of `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Since Intent Handlers that do asynchronous operations *must* return a Promise, you can simply return the one that is returned by the rp/then/catch chain. Something like changing this line should work:

```
return rp(options)
```

Comment: Wow that was it, cant believe I didnt think of that. Thanks!

Comment: easy enough to miss!

Answer (score 1):

I have modified your code to return a Promise. Check if this works for you.

```
app.intent("late drop", (conv, {
  term,
  year
}) => {

  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

    var date = new Date();
    var month;
    if (term == null) {
      month = date.getMonth();

      if (month >= 9 && month <= 12) {
        term = "fall";
        //console.log("fall")
      } else if (month >= 1 && month <= 5) {
        term = "spring";
        //console.log("spring")
      } else {
        term = "summer";
        //console.log("summer")
      }
    }
    if (year == null) {
      yearDig = date.getFullYear();
      year = yearDig;
      //console.log(year)
    }
    var strYear = year.toString();
    var semester = term + strYear.substr(2);
    const options = {
      uri: `https://www.registrar.psu.edu/academic_calendar/${semester}.cfm`,
      transform: function (body) {
        return cheerio.load(body);
      }
    };
    rp(options)
      .then(($) => {
        let map = {};
        let columnOne = [];
        let columnThree = [];

        $('table').find('tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function (index, element) {
          columnOne.push($(element).text());
        });

        $('table').find('tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function (index, element) {
          columnThree.push($(element).text());
        });

        columnOne.forEach((item, i) => {
          map[item] = columnThree[i];
        });

        console.log(map);
        date = map["2Late Drop Begins"];
        conv.ask("The late drop period begins on " + map["2Late Drop Begins"])
        resolve()
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        conv.ask("An error occured, please try again.");
        reject()
      })
  });

});
```

Hope that helps!